# Get distinct records values

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to query for objects with not same values on some field? For example I have Records:

```
{ id : 1, name : "my_name", salary : 1200 }
{ id : 2, name : "my_name", salary : 800 }
{ id : 3, name : "john", salary : 500 }
```

Query : find all with NOT_THE_SAME(name)

I just want records with id 1 and 3 because I specified that I don't want records with same value in field `name` or 2 and 3, it does not matter in this situation.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use [`db.collection.distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) to get back an array of unique values:

```
> db.test.distinct("name")
[ "my_name", "john" ]
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also use a distinct sentence with filtered collection. For example, you can get distinct values of names from salaries over 800 with the following query:

```
db.test.distinct("name", { "salary": { $gt: 800 } })
```

Answer (score 18):

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$name", salary: {$max: "$salary"}}}])
```

should list all names *with their salaries*.

`$max` returns the highest salary per element. You could also choose `$first` etc, see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't care about the content of varying fields but want the whole records, this will keep the (whole, thanks to `$$ROOT`) first document found for each "name" :

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$name", 
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }}
])
```

`$replaceRoot` will serve them as documents instead of encapsulating them in a `doc` field with `_id`.

If you are concerned about the content of the varying fields, I guess you may want to sort the documents first :

```
db.coll.aggregate([
  { "$sort": { "$salary": 1 }},
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$name", 
    "doc": { "$first": "$$ROOT" } 
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. This was something I wouldn't find very easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### Mongo DB version > 3.4

```
db.test.distinct("name")
```

#### Mongo DB version < 3.4

```
db.test.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$name", salary: {$max: "$salary"}}}])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.runCommand ( {
    distinct: "CollectionName", 
    key: "key", 
    query: { "createdDate": { 
        $gte:new ISODate("2017-04-04T23:59:59Z"),
        $lte:new ISODate("2017-04-25T23:59:59Z")}} } )
```

this query helps find data in collection , will fetch value of key from all documents which satisfy condition of between date

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - added comments ,hope this helps