# Mongodb find() query : return only unique values (no duplicates)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of documents :

```
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork1",
    "pointID": "point001",
    "param": "param1"
}
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork2",
    "pointID": "point002",
    "param": "param2"
}
{
    "networkID": "myNetwork1",
    "pointID": "point003",
    "param": "param3"
}
...
```

pointIDs are unique but networkIDs are not.

Is it possible to query Mongodb in such a way that the result will be :
[myNetwork1,myNetwork2]

right now I only managed to return [myNetwork1,myNetwork2,myNetwork1]

I need a list of unique networkIDs to populate an autocomplete select2 component.
As I may have up to 50K documents I would prefer mongoDb to filter the results at the query level.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I think you can use `db.collection.distinct(fields,query)`

You will be able to get the distinct values in your case for NetworkID.

It should be something like this :

`db.collection.distinct('NetworkID')`

Comment: What if I want to get full record? This will only return `NetworkID`.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince, what full record? `distinct` returns all the unique values for a field. Returning a record or records doesn't make sense in this context.  You'll have to use the aggregation pipeline [`$group` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for distinct + records.

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince: if you want a full record, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44887521/1587329

Comment: @HalfBloodPrince For full records you want to use an aggregation with `$$ROOT`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59756228/812102).

Comment: You put the signature of the method `distinct`, but I would like to know about the second parameter, for an example, how can I distinct by id and get this data until a date? Like I have a property called PaymentDate in this table.