# How to use distinct with aggregate method for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, distinct

I have some conditions and a level to check while fetching records from collection using MongoDB.

For this I am using below

```
def cursorOutput = dataSetCollection.find(whereObject,criteriaObject)
```

Which is working fine. but I want to use distinct with combination to above query.

```
def distinctMIdList = dataSetCollection.distinct(hierarchyField,whereObject)
```

Above is the query for distinct. How to combine two query.

I tried below which is not working

```
def cursorOutput = dataSetCollection.find(whereObject,criteriaObject).distinct("manager id")
```

**whereObject** is a condition to fetch results and **criteriaObject** is fields to fetch.

Distinct query is giving me result with only Manager id field but I am looking for other field also(use of criteriaObject).

Finally how to combine above two query. I searched for pipeline where $distinct is not available.

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values

Answer (score 0):

Map function:

```
   var mapFunction = function() {
       if(/*your criteria*/) {
           emit("manager_id", this.manager_id);
       }
    };
```

Reduce Function:

```
   var reduceFunction = function(managerFiled,values){
       return Array.unique(values);
   }
```