# Finding distinct from collections in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

Our previous implementation for finding distinct elements from a collection used to be :

```
List<String> names = mongoClient.getDB(dbName).getCollection(collectionName).distinct(NAME_KEY);
```

Trying to upgrade this into the current implementation with mongo 3.3.0+ as tried is :

```
List<String> names = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName)
                        .getCollection(collectionName, TDocType.class)
                        .distinct(NAME_KEY, String.class); // compile error - required Class<TResult>
```

Have also given a try to

```
.distinct(NAME_KEY, TDocType.class)  // doesn't work
```

What shall be the target type of the iterable in this case?

***Edit*** - The question is not a duplicate of [Get distinct records values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values) since the implementation has changed over the upgrade of `mongodb-java-driver`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Improved answer from @jyemin**

```
List<String> list = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName)
                .getCollection(collectionName, TDocType.class)
                .distinct(NAME_KEY, String.class)
                .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

**Original answer**

You can try something like this.

```
DistinctIterable<String> iterable = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).
            .getCollection(collectionName, TDocType.class).distinct(NAME_KEY, String.class);
MongoCursor<String> cursor = iterable.iterator();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    list.add(cursor.next());
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Also this can be further improved as `for(String str : iterable) { list.add(str); }` instead of using Cursor above. The way I am using it is `List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList(mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName, TDocType.class).distinct(NAME_KEY, String.class));` where the `Lists` is from google collection.

Comment: Or more simply: 
    List<String> list = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).getCollection(collectionName, TDocType.class).distinct(NAME_KEY, String.class).into(new ArrayList<>());

Answer (score 0):

for those who already have `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy` in their deps  :

```
// import static org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.toSet;.
toSet(distinctIterable);
```

Example

```
DistinctIterable<String> distinctIterable = getCollection()
            .distinct(FIELD_ID, query.getQueryObject(), String.class);
return toSet(distinctIterable);
```