# Get entries from collection that have unique values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let collection be

```
[
    {area:'121',name:'r',age:'1'},
    {area:'122',name:'rt',age:'21'},
    {area:'121',name:'r',age:'1'}

]
```

I want query that will return

```
[
    {area:'121',name:'r',age:'1'},
    {area:'122',name:'rt',age:'21'}     
]
```

i.e entry that have unique **area** value. I tried to search and use **distinct**

```
collections.collection('collection')
                        .distinct('area', (err, sus) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                                resp.status(501).send()
                            } else {
                                console.log(sus)
                                resp.send(sus)
                            }
                        })
```

but the output is

```
["121","122"]
```

This is giving me only distinct values but i want the full entry. How to get that?

Comment: You can use the aggregate operation to get unique values,  i guess. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values/44887521#44887521

Comment: As specified in one of the duplicates, you need to run an aggregation pipeline like `collections.collection('collection').aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$area",
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "age": { "$first": "$age" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "area": "$_id",
            "name": 1,
            "age": 1
        }
    }
], (err, sus) => {
 if (err) {
  console.log(err)
  resp.status(501).send()
 } else {
  console.log(sus)
  resp.send(sus)
 }
})`