# Count distinct value in Array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
    "id": "K",
    "powers": [
        {
            "label": "a",
            "Rating": 7
        },
        {
            "label": "b",
            "Rating": 3
        },
        {
            "label": "c",
            "Rating": 4
        },
        {
            "label": "d",
            "Rating": 5
        }
    ],
    "phy": {
        "height": 67,
        "weight": 150
    }
}
```

For this collection, I want to count how many distinct powers each id has.

I want the result as - ID =K, distinct power label - 4

Comment: Does this `"id": "K"` duplicated in any other doc's ?

Comment: no , it's unique

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get distinct records values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values)

Answer (score 0):

So the easiest way to get it done is

```
/** db.collection.distinct('field on which distinct is needed', condition) */

db.collection.distinct('powers.label', {"id" : "K"})
```

As it will be an array, You can do `.length` in code to get the unique length.

**Ref :** [.distinct()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/index.html)

Comment: Can you please show with length for all ID's . Two columns - ID , Length ( number of powers)

Comment: @Kulbirsingh : What do you men *show with length for all ID's* ?