# How to get unique values in python from MongoDB?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, duplicates

I want to get unique data for **ssn_variations** i.e unique `b_no` and `ssn_no` without duplication.
I am getting data from `mongodb`

```
if cr_no in list(json_cr.keys()):
            cr_data = json_cr[cr_no]
            if "ssn_variations" in list(cr_data.keys()):
                ssn_variations = cr_data["ssn_variations"]
                for var_key in ssn_variations.keys():
                    variations = ssn_variations[var_key]
                    b_no = variations["b_no"].strip()
                    ssn_no = variations["ssn_no"].strip()
                    if b_no != "" and ssn_no != "":
                        if b_type == "Borrower":
                            if b_no == "1":
                                self.C1212.append({"borrower_name": encompass_full_name, "ssn_no": ssn_no})
                        else:
                            if b_no == "2":
                                self.C1212.append({"borrower_name": encompass_full_name, "ssn_no": ssn_no})
```

I am getting a response like this

```
{
            "ssn_variations" : {
                "1" : {
                    "b_no" : "5",
                    "ssn_no" : "32323"
                },
                "2" : {
                    "b_no" : "2",
                    "ssn_no" : "232323"
                },
                "3" : {
                    "b_no" : "2",
                    "ssn_no" : "232323"
                }
            }
        },
```

But I want a response like below without duplication.

```
{
            "ssn_variations" : {
                "1" : {
                    "b_no" : "5",
                    "ssn_no" : "32323"
                },
                "2" : {
                    "b_no" : "2",
                    "ssn_no" : "232323"
                },  
        },
```

I tried `set` method but not getting the desired output

MongoDb query to get data

```
    db.Document_Details_Table.find({"loanNumberId":"4343434","documentId":"434343"})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

Comment: this might be better handled by MongoDB than Python, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655506/get-distinct-records-values/44887521#44887521

Comment: @JanWilamowski I updated my question. Please check the mongo query I used to handle data. Can you help me with this.

Comment: I'm not an expert on MongoDB but have you looked at the linked question? There are multiple options described, I suggest trying those out first.

Comment: @JanWilamowski I have almost tried all queries.

Comment: @ManasRanjanPati Paste a sample document from the collection. the whole thing.

Comment: It will be helpful If I can get unique data suing Python only.